# How to prevent JavaScript from filling in unspecified parts of style

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I set the style of an element with JS it seems to fill out the parts of the style which I intentionally left unspecified.

For example, if I set the transition style

```js
el.style.transition = 'width .2s'
```

The html changes to

```html
<div style="width: 50px; transition: width 0.2s ease 0s;"></div>
```

Which is inconvenient, because I want to be able to set the timing function in css without using `!important`

Does anyone know any simple ways to get around this, ideally without manipulating `el.attributes.style`?

Comment: 'ease' is the default timing value; it has nothing to do with javascript. even if you set the width transition of .2s with pure CSS, the transition-timing-function would still be 'ease'. i guess its your browser who is filling the empty timing with the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with JavaScript. That's the default behaviour of `transition`.
You could, for instance, try and make it the way you want by either specifying the duration yourself or by using `el.style.transitionDuration`

```
el.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to just use the specific rules! Thanks Ikdemm